# Send a variable with link in non visible way

Tags: php, facebook, url

So I'm trying to send the description of a facebook gallery with the link of the clicked gallery.
Currently it takes the aid and name, but if I also send the dec then the link will be very ugly and long.

```
echo "<a href='gallery.php?action=list_pics&aid=" . $values['aid'] . "&name=" . $values['name'] . "'>";
```

Is there any way of sending it whithout making the link overly ugly?

Comment: Aside from using sessions? there isn't any other way.

Comment: If you want to send the value which is long and ugly through the link, then the link will always be aswell

Answer (score 0):

use `echo "<a href='javascript:sendData()'>Click Here</a>"`, this will link to javascript function `sendData()` and then have a function called `sendData()` in javascript which sends data to gallery.php by POST methd.